# VB Listbox remove item

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

In a listbox I want to remove an item but keep the others.
I've tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items.IndexOf("TEST"))
```

Googled around but couldn't find a working method.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: `Remove` takes an item/object representing what you want to remove.  `RemoveAt` takes an integer representing the index of the item to remove.  (WinForms)

Comment: @plutonix thanks, also an option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will work with WebForms**

First find the `ListItem` you want to remove:

```
Dim liItem As ListItem = ListBox1.Items.FindByValue("TEST")
```

You could also find by Text instead of value:

```
Dim liItem As ListItem = ListBox1.Items.FindByText("TEST")
```

Then remove it:

```
If ( liItem IsNot Nothing) Then

    ListBox1.items.Remove(liItem)

end If
```

**UPDATE - This will work with Windows Forms**

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.Items.IndexOf("TEST"))
```

Or this:

```
Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.FindString("TEST")
If ( index <> -1 ) Then
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index)
End If
```

Comment: When I try your code it says: Type 'ListItem' is not defined.